# In AND condition which side evaluate first in python?

Tags: python

I have an AND statement, the right side condition of the statement, can be checked only, if the first one returns true.

```
if foo is not None and foo.passes_the_test():
  # do something
```

Does the python skip the right side condition check if the left side returns false, thus preventing the Exception if foo is None and foo method is called?

Comment: true. my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the first statement is false, the second one is not checked.